# How to separate fields in a text file with a delimiter

Tags: unix, sed

I have a scenario where I have a text file and I want to separate the row values in the text file with a particular delimiter (say, `:`).

I have generated the text file by storing the output of an SQL query into a text file.

The contents of the text file are

```
field 1.2     xxxx
field 2.7.1   xxxx
field 1.9     xxxx
field 1.4     xxxx
field 2.7.1   xxxx
```

I tried this:

```
cat /tmp/file.txt | sed 's/ /:/g'
```

but as the space is not consistent over the rows, this does not work for me.

How can I do this?
the output that i am expecting here is something like this

```
field :1.2    :xxxx
field :2.7.1  :xxxx
field :1.9    :xxxx
field :1.4    :xxxx
field :2.7.1  :xxxx
```

Comment: adding complete expected output would help clarify your requirement.. as of now answers you've got do not all produce the same output..

Comment: yes i have edited my question and pasted the expected output

Comment: Most SQL applications can store output in computer-readable form with an option. The padded output you say you are expecting doesn't look particularly useful; you would probably be better off without the padding, perhaps with a standard format like CSV or JSON.

Answer (score 0):

space-space-asterisk. The first space to say there has to be one, the second with an asterisk to say zero-or-more extras. `sed 's/  */:/g'`

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed, to replace two or more spaces with colon:

```
sed -E 's/ {2,}/:/' file
```

or second string matching one or more spaces:

```
sed -E 's/ +/:/2' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`tr` with its "squeeze" option](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#Squeezing-and-deleting):

```
$ tr -s ' ' : < input
field:1.2:xxxx
field:2.7.1:xxxx
field:1.9:xxxx
field:1.4:xxxx
field:2.7.1:xxxx
```

This squeezes any sequence of repeated spaces into a single one, which is then replaced by a colon.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed -E 's/[[:blank:]]+/&:/g' /tmp/file.txt
field :1.2     :xxxx
field :2.7.1   :xxxx
field :1.9     :xxxx
field :1.4     :xxxx
field :2.7.1   :xxxx
```

- [no need to use cat](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html), many cli tools accept both stdin and file inputs
- `[[:blank:]]` to match space and tab characters, if you know there are only space characters, use literal space
- `+` to match one or more of blank characters, note the use of `-E` option to enable ERE. Some `sed` versions might support only `-r` instead of `-E`

  - If ERE is not available, use `sed 's/[[:blank:]]\{1,\}/&:/g'`
- `&` in replacement section refers to entire matched string